# Use Slider to update zoom factor on Canvas

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an simple SwiftUI project that needs to use a slider to trigger a redraw and update a data model used to draw lines on a Canvas.

I'm new to SwiftUI and picking up some tidbits around stack and other sites I've figured out how to use the slider and draw data on the Canvas. The issue I have now is that when I use the slider it doesn't trigger the data in my view model to change and trigger the Canvas to redraw. I do get the initial two lines I add in init. The redraw should still draw two lines but increase the space between them based on the value in the slider.

My code beginnings below:
Data Model

```
import Foundation


class sliderZoom: ObservableObject {
    @Published var zoom = 1.0
    @Published var lines: [line] = []
    
    init (){
        var nl = line(points: [CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 100.0)])
        addLines(newLine: nl)
        nl = line(points: [CGPoint(x: (10 * zoom), y: 0.0), CGPoint(x: (10 * zoom), y: 100.0)])
        addLines(newLine: nl)
    }
    
    func addLines(newLine: line){
        lines.append(newLine)
    }
}


public struct line {
    let points: [CGPoint]
}
```

Content View

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var globalZoom = sliderZoom()

    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Slider!")
            .padding()
        Canvas {context, size in
            for line in globalZoom.lines {
                var path = Path()
                path.addLines(line.points)
                context.stroke(path, with: .color(.red), lineWidth: 1.0)
            }
        }
        Slider(value: $globalZoom.zoom, in: 0.3...10.0)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 10, alignment: .trailing)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note I'm aware of scaleEffect but this scales the entire view which is not what I'm after.

Comment: I think I have a path forwards - not sure if this is the best/most performant approach but the slider has an onchanged handler. I have this now: .onChange(of: globalZoom.zoom, perform: sliderChanged). This in turn calls a function in the data model to redraw the lines. The lines are drawn with the correct spacing using the value in the slider. Happy to mark this as answered unless a senior dev has a better approach :)